# Power series expansion of $\arctan (x)$ centered at $x=0$ extends to $x=1$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, power-series

In my real analysis class (this is a HW question) I have been given the following problem:

1. Show that $\dfrac{1}{1 + x^2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n x^{2 n}$ when $|x|<1$.
2. Show that $\arctan (x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^n x^{2n + 1}}{2n + 1}$ when $|x|<1$.
3. Show that series for $\arctan (x)$ in the previous part also holds when $x=1$.

Here is my work for parts 1 & 2.

Since $|x^2| < 1$ as $|x| < 1$, we have that
\begin{align*}
                \dfrac{1}{1+x^2}&= \dfrac{1}{1-(-x^2)}\\
                &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(-x^2\right)^n\\
                &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n x^{2n}
            \end{align*}
whenever $|x| < 1$.

We know that $\dfrac{d}{dx}\arctan (x) =\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$, and thus, we may integrate termwise on the power series expansion of $\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$ which we have already found:
\begin{align*}
                \arctan(x)&= \int \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n x^{2n} dx\\
                &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int (-1)^n x^{2n} dx\\
                &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{2n+1}.
            \end{align*}

I am unsure how to proceed with part $3$. I found it peculiar how [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1858869/is-it-possible-to-have-a-power-series-for-arctanx-centered-at-1) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3469364/taylor-series-of-arctan-x-at-x-1) both use complex analysis to solve it, which I'm sure is not what my professor intends (we have done nothing with complex numbers in this course). If I had to guess, we are intended to use Abel's theorem, but I don't see how this question meets all the necessary requirements of Abel's Theorem.  I'm looking for intuition on how to use the theorem. Thanks!

Comment: @ClydeKertzer You can use [Abel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen The question has been edited extensively since my comments, which I've deleted, were posted.

Comment: I see @MarkViola. Thanks for the explanation. Everything makes sense now :-)

Comment: This is famously known as the Leibniz $\pi$ formula. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80 has a neat proof without using any fancy series tools. Using the form of Abel's theorem stated here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1827301/proof-of-leibniz-pi-formula, observe that $A:=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}$ converges by the alternating series test, so Abel tells us $\lim_{x\nearrow 1} \arctan(x)=A$. As $\arctan(x)$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$, indeed we have $\arctan(1)=A$.

Comment: Thanks! If you post this as an answer I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is famously known as the Leibniz $\pi$ formula. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80 has a neat proof without using any fancy series tools. Using the form of Abel's theorem stated here: [Proof of Leibniz $\pi$ formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1827301/proof-of-leibniz-pi-formula), observe that $A:=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}$ converges by the alternating series test, so Abel tells us $\lim_{x\nearrow 1} \arctan(x)=A$. As $\arctan(x)$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$, indeed we have $\arctan(1)=A$.